# How to web scrape from two websites and print into excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xpath, web-scraping

I have an excel file named 'MLB_names.xlsx'. In this file I have one sheet named 'Home' that includes formulas I would like to preserve. (Sheet 1)

I am trying to add two web scrapes to this excel file. I would like to the first web scrape, the MLB batters, to be printed to a new sheet named 'batters'. (Sheet 2)

I would like the second web scrape, the MLB pitchers, to be printed to a new sheet named 'pitchers'. (Sheet 3)

I will include some more info about the project below...

**Sheet 1): 'Home'**

This is a sheet I already have saved. I would like to preserve the formulas in this sheet if possible.

**Sheet 2): 'Batters'**

I have scraped all the names and ages of the 2018 MLB batters.

Here is the code for my 1st successful scrape:

```
#import modules

from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring    
import pandas as pd

#fetch batting url

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-batting.shtml"

#remove HTML Markup

content = str(urlopen(url).read())
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)

#create column titles

columns = ("names", "age")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)    

#parse HTML

for idx, pitcher_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]')):
    names = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    age = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="age"]/text()')[0]        

    #create dataframe
    df.loc[idx] = (names, age)

    #print data 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MLB_names.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
```

**Sheet 3): 'Pitchers'**

Now for my 2nd scrape... It's basically the same coding but now for the pitchers:

```
#import modules

from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml.html import fromstring    
import pandas as pd

#fetch pitching url

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-pitching.shtml"

#remove HTML Markup

content = str(urlopen(url).read())
comment = content.replace("-->","").replace("<!--","")
tree = fromstring(comment)

#create column titles

columns = ("names", "age")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)    

#parse HTML

for idx, pitcher_row in enumerate(tree.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"stats_table")]//tr[contains(@class,"full_table")]')):
    names = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="player"]/a')[0].text
    age = pitcher_row.xpath('.//td[@data-stat="age"]/text()')[0]        

    #create dataframe
    df.loc[idx] = (names, age)

    #print data 
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MLB_names.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2')
    writer.save()
```

Just to reiterate what I am looking for...

1) maintain 'Home' sheet with formulas.

Not sure if I should use the following code for this step:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_excel

my_sheet_name = 'Home'
df = read_excel('MLB_names.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Home')
```

2) initiate scrape 1 and scrape 2

This part has been completed. I could use help creating the 2 separate dataframes, though, so I can complete the next step.

3) print to excel using pandas

sheet 1) 'Home' 
remain in tact with formulas

sheet 2) 'batters'

sheet 3) 'pitchers'

Comment: Is this something you are familiar with, @petezurich? Your last answer helped tremendously with my learning =)

Comment: try `pd.read_html("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-batting.shtml")` will return list of dataframes from the  url and works fine for me